# regex for 3 numbers after string

Tags: regex, replace

I've a problem, I have a link on each page of my website linking to a different contact form which does'nt exist. for example, on one page it links to contact_123.html, another contact_122.html, another contact_124.html etc... I want to do a find and replace on this to change any contact_"any 3 numbers".html to just contact.html.

Does anyone know the regex to do this. Cheers!

Comment: In php, which uses the perl regular expression engine, use `.+[0-9]{3}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regex to search for: `contact_\d{3}\.html`

How to do actual search&replace depends what tool/environment you're using

Comment: The `[]` isn't necessary I think, so could be shortened to `contact_\d{3}\.html` :)